# How do I export all variables from a project to .csv so that I can then import them into a Python environment?

Tags: python, r, rstudio

I have a large project in RStudio that I would like to attempt some things with in Python and want to know if there is a way of effectively packaging up all of the environment variables (data frames, lists, atomic vectors, etc.) and importing those into Spyder (Python).

If not directly possible, I am aware that I can read files into Python in numerous ways, and as such am wondering if there is a method I could use to iterate through my R environment and save all of the variables as .csv files so that I can later read them into Spyder?

I have tried this code but to no avail:

```
files <- mget(ls())

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  write.csv(files[[i]], paste(names(files[i]), ".csv", sep = ""))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at some of the packages for transferring data, but to specifically answer your question:

```
x1 <- "hello"
x2 <- "these are some"
x3 <- "objects"

for (i in names(.GlobalEnv)) {
  write.csv(.GlobalEnv[[i]], file = sprintf("%s.csv", i))
}
```

You could more explicitly export the objects by storing the objects for export in a separate environment, too.